# Vector as edges of graph

Tags: c++

```
for(int i = 0,u,v,w;i < M;++i){
        scanf("%d %d %d",&u,&v,&w);

        L[u].push_back(v);
        W[u].push_back(w);

        L[v].push_back(u);
        W[v].push_back(w);
```

If we consider L and w as two vectors then what does this piece of code lead to?

Comment: What do you mean by "What does this piece of code lead to?"

Comment: In memory like if i say if an element is added to vector we understand this as element added to a vector just like an array but here we push back an element v to L[u]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will just keep adding M elements in to the vectors assuming L and w are already defined and memory is allocated for user entered u and v sizes.